# meteor add barbatus:typescript => ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: angular, typescript, meteor, ionic-framework

Trying to follow tutorial https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/meteor-server-side https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/meteor-server-side

I have already set `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

I'm running on Windows 10 under a proxy server!

But when I try to install typescript for meteor

Thats the error I got:

```
D:\WhatsApp Clone with Metor and Ionic 2 CLI\whatsapp\api>meteor add barbatus:typescript
C:\Users\marcelo-gf\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0-rc.7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\WhatsApp Clone with Metor and Ionic 2 CLI\whatsapp\uuid\bin\uuid'
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:955:11)
    at Object.wrapper (C:\tools\fs\files.js:1594:35)
    at Object.files.(anonymous function) [as stat] (C:\tools\fs\files.js:1729:27)
    at symlinkWithOverwrite (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:727:17)
    at optimisticReaddir.forEach.item (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:554:11)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at walk (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:462:34)
    at optimisticReaddir.forEach.item (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:551:11)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at walk (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:462:34)
    at Builder.copyDirectory (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:589:5)
    at _.each (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack.js:1450:17)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\marcelo-gf\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0-rc.7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
    at Isopack.saveToPath (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack.js:1449:9)
    at exports.Tropohouse._saveIsopack (C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:337:15)
    at buildmessage.enterJob (C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:526:16)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:515:22
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at Object.download (C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:427:20)
    at C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:613:18
    at enterJobAsync.then (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:572:21)
    at C:\Users\marcelo-gf\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0-rc.7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\fiber_pool.js:43:40
 => awaited here:
    at Promise.await (C:\Users\marcelo-gf\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0-rc.7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:60:12)
    at Object.forkJoin (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:567:10)
    at exports.Tropohouse.downloadPackagesMissingFromMap (C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:609:18)
    at C:\tools\project-context.js:814:25
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at C:\tools\project-context.js:813:20
    at C:\tools\packaging\catalog\catalog.js:100:5
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at Object.catalog.runAndRetryWithRefreshIfHelpful (C:\tools\packaging\catalog\catalog.js:99:31)
    at ProjectContext._downloadMissingPackages (C:\tools\project-context.js:812:13)
    at C:\tools\project-context.js:285:9
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at ProjectContext._completeStagesThrough (C:\tools\project-context.js:275:18)
    at Profile.run (C:\tools\project-context.js:267:12)
    at Function.run (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:490:12)
    at ProjectContext.prepareProjectForBuild (C:\tools\project-context.js:266:13)
    at C:\tools\cli\commands-packages.js:2155:20
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at Command.func (C:\tools\cli\commands-packages.js:2154:27)
    at C:\tools\cli\main.js:1491:23

D:\WhatsApp Clone with Metor and Ionic 2 CLI\whatsapp\api>
```

Comment: It seems that there is no node_modules folder on your path before uuid which is a npm package if I get it right. Did you call `meteor npm install` before running your app?

Comment: It will be nice if you copy the code in your post, in case the link is not accessible anymore

Comment: NOPE, still have the same error!

Comment: Upgraded GIT version to 2.8.1, then after run "meteor npm install" had the same error when tried to install "meteor add barbatus:typescript".

Comment: Try running as a administrator as this could be a permissions issue.

Comment: Hi JamiDer, it all have been done with administrator account. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my friends, I have an answer, actualy I don't now why, but now I can continue the tutorial. I have just started from the begin and instaling the latest version of all components.

```
> D:\WhatsApp Clone with Metor and Ionic 2 CLI\whatsapp\api>meteor add
> barbatus:typescript
> 
> Changes to your project's package version selections:
> 
> barbatus:typescript           added, version 0.6.12
> barbatus:typescript-compiler  added, version 0.9.12
> barbatus:typescript-runtime   added, version 1.0.2
> 
> 
> barbatus:typescript: TypeScript for Meteor
> 
> D:\WhatsApp Clone with Metor and Ionic 2 CLI\whatsapp\api>ionic
> --version
> 3.19.0
> 
> D:\WhatsApp Clone with Metor and Ionic 2 CLI\whatsapp\api>cordova
> --version
> 8.0.0
> 
> D:\WhatsApp Clone with Metor and Ionic 2 CLI\whatsapp\api>meteor
> --version Meteor 1.6.0.1
```